# Are Visual Studio 2010 Professional Solutions/Projects 100% compatible with Visual Studio 2010 Premium Solutions/Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am just wondering on what version of Visual Studio 2010 to install (Professional or Premium) If there are a few people in the team with a mix of VS2010 professional/premium, would opening solution/project files be an issue, ie incorrect version or prompts to upgrade prjects..

Projects include: asp.net mvc, database and silverlight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general projects created by the same version of different editions are compatible with one another - if the edition installed lacks features necessary to load a given project, it will inform you of such and simply not load the project.